# Thread-safe Auto-Filling Reference - synchronized vs Atomic Reference with Soft/Weak Reference

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety

I'm working on creating an auto-updating reference in java.

**The use case** There are immutable objects that should be lazy initialed, including static objects. These objects will have spikes of calls thus having a simple Supplier call each time for ( effectively ) the same object would wasteful. But holding the object somewhat consistently for the bigger objects for classes that may be held in the class loader much longer than the value may need to be there. At the same time, the use case also involves long-life multi-threaded applications; so having a simple SoftReference or WeakReference isn't enough because neither are thread safe (I'm looking at 1.8 source code where both inherit and directly use Reference fields and methods (no overriding), where no volatile, synchronized keyword are being used, nor any obvious atomic protocols ).

**tl:dr the use case** It boils down to the object has to allow the garbage collector to clear the value, but being thread-safe. The only way to enable the garbage collector while holding the value ( to my knowledge ), is to use SoftReference or WeakReference; both of which are not thread-safe.

I'm trying to avoid using synchronized getters/setters and volatile the reference type; we can ensure thread-safety by locks to block other threads and a strong reference to block the garbage collector. The main concern here is the fact that blocks are expensive.

Other options involve the Atomic Reference class, which is being considered to be used in conjunction with a Soft or Weak Reference. Either the finalized but mutating AtomicReference holding the Soft/Weak Reference or a volatile Soft/Weak Reference holding the AtomicReference with synchronized blocks which would defeat the purpose of using the AtomicReference. So to have both the Atomic and Soft/Weak References is to have the Atomic hold the Soft/Weak. However, having AtomicReference hold the Soft/Weak Reference may not have memory-visibility to the end value because the Soft/Weak is does not necessarily ensure it?

**tl:dr the post** Would an AtomicReference holding a Soft or Weak Reference actually have memory-visibility even though the Reference class does not have any direct memory-visibility insurance? Thus effectively offers the same thread-safety level as the more costly volatile and locks combo?

Comment: `WeakReference` seems wrong.  `WeakReference` basically means, I am only interested in this object if there is a strong reference to it somewhere else.  `SoftReference` sounds more like what you want.  It means, I am interested in this object, but I am willing to let go of it if memory is getting tight.

Comment: Can you explain why you think `SoftReference` is not thread safe? A `SoftReference` object is _almost_ immutable: There is no method that ordinary Java code can call to change its value. Only the garbage collector can change it, but the [javadoc for SoftReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) says, "...At that time [the GC] may choose to clear _atomically_ all soft references to that object and..." So, if the action of the garbage collector is atomic, and no other thread can touch it, where's the problem?

Comment: The actual Reference will be loose, it honestly will depend more on the specific use case to determine the actual reference type. e.g. if it's more a large cache that takes more time/resources to create, Soft would be more prefered.

Comment: @jameslarge - I wasn't aware the gc processes it atomically. Though it does make sense; thank you very much. I consider this to solve the question.

Comment: The garbage collector’s activities, including clearing of references, must be thread safe, as otherwise the entire safety of a Java environment would be worthless. But since you want to (re)create the referent on demand, you have to encapsulate the `SoftReference` in a thread safe holder object anyway, as you can’t set a new referent, so each time you create a new referent, you must create a new `SoftReference` instance as well and publish it in a thread safe manner.